# Product of a closed subgroup and a discrete subgroup in a Hausdorff group

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a Hausdorff group. Let $A$ be a closed subgroup of $G$ and $B$ be a discrete subgroup of $G$ (note $B$ is closed since $G$ is Hausdorff). Is the product set $AB$ necessarily closed in $G$?

Comment: A subgroup is not closed because the group is Hausdorff: consider $\Bbb Q$ inside $\Bbb R$, e.g. The title mentions discrete while the question does not?

Comment: @hanno sorry my typo, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no, assuming you meant for $B$ to be the discrete subgroup, which seems likely. In the additive group $\mathbb R$ we have two discrete, closed subgroups $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z\sqrt 2$, but the sum of these subgroups is dense and not all of $\mathbb R$ and hence is in particular not closed.